# How to properly indent with python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

Indentation seems pretty straightforward, and terminal prints back the proper indentation, but the same indentation is not reflected in my saved Word docx.
Am I doing something wrong here?

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
    
worddoc = Document()
paragraph = worddoc.add_paragraph('Left Indent Test')
paragraph.left_indent = Inches(.25)
print(paragraph.left_indent.inches)
    
worddoc.save('left_indent.docx')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turns out to be a documentation error.

If you use the new API it works:

```
paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent = Inches(0.25)
```

The `left_indent` property was moved to the `paragraph_format` "sub-object" a couple releases back as the `ParagraphFormat` class is used by both the `Paragraph` and `ParagraphStyle` objects.

If you'll file a bug report in the `python-docx` issue tracker on GitHub we'll get the documentation updated next time we're in there.